# Calling function in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am working with cloud code for the first time and am trying to call the following function:

```
       let friendRequest: PFObject = self.friendRequestsToCurrentUser[sender.tag] as PFObject
      let fromUser: PFUser = friendRequest[FriendRequestKeyFrom] as PFUser
      //call the cloud code function that adds the current user to the user who sent the request and pass in the friendRequest id as a parameter
        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("addFriendToFriendsRelation", withParameters: ["friendRequest": friendRequest.objectId]) { (object:AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        let friendsRelation: PFRelation = PFUser.currentUser()!.relationForKey("friends")
         friendsRelation.addObject(fromUser)
             self.currentUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                 if succeeded {
                 } else {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

After implementing the function I was required to add "!" to the objectId in the parameter to unwrap it. 
However, doing this leaves me with the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(AnyObject!, NSError!) -> Void' to
>   expected argument type 'PFIdResultsBlock?'

What must I change in order to call this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PFIdResultsBlock` corresponds to the following signature `(AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void` so try to change your code to this:

```
let friendRequest: PFObject = self.friendRequestsToCurrentUser[sender.tag] as PFObject
let fromUser: PFUser = friendRequest[FriendRequestKeyFrom] as PFUser

//call the cloud code function that adds the current user to the user who sent the request and pass in the friendRequest id as a parameter
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("addFriendToFriendsRelation", withParameters: ["friendRequest": friendRequest.objectId]) { (object:AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    let friendsRelation: PFRelation = PFUser.currentUser()!.relationForKey("friends")
    friendsRelation.addObject(fromUser)
    self.currentUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if succeeded {

        } else {

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `PFObject?` instead of `AnyObject!`.

Comment: I tried PFObject but am still getting the error. Thank you for the suggestion.